# C# generics type conversion Decimal to Float - "Cannot convert type 'T1?' to 'T2'"

Tags: c#, generics, decimal

I am trying to implement a class that performs generic functionality on IntegerUpDown and DecimalUpDown WPF controls. Using the class defined below (simplified for illustration).
TDataType will be either int or float.
TUpDownControl will be either IntegerUpDown or DecimalUpDown WPF controls
TControlDataType will be either Integer or Decimal

```
class MyGenericClass<TDataType, TUpDownControl, TControlDataType>
    where TControlDataType   : struct, IComparable<TControlDataType>, IFormattable
    where TDataType      : struct, IComparable, IComparable<TDataType>
    where TUpDownControl : CommonNumericUpDown<TControlDataType>
{
    private TUpDownControl m_control;

    public MyGenericClass(TUpDownControl ctrl)
    {
        m_control = ctrl;
    }

    public TDataType getVal()
    {
        TDataType val = (TDataType)m_control.Value;
        return val;
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is when I try to obtain the value and convert from Decimal/Integer to Float/Int I get the error
**"Cannot convert type 'TControlDataType?' to 'TDataType'"**
Does anyone have an idea how to get round this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That conversion cannot actually work; you cannot cast at runtime from one value type to another.
(code like `(float)myDecimal` only works because the compiler emits IL that actually converts the value; that cannot happen for generics)

Instead, you can use `Convert.ChangeType()` to explicitly convert a boxed value to any other numeric type.
However, this is relatively slow; it involves two box/unbox pairs and a virtual interface call.

To be faster, you can compile your own converter using expression trees:

```
static class ConverterHolder<TIn, TOut> {
    public static Func<TIn, TOut> Converter;
    static ConverterHolder() {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TIn));
        Converter = Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, TOut>>(
            Expression.Convert(parameter, typeof(TOut)), 
            parameter
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm relatively new to c# and am not familiar with expressions trees. Can you explain a little more. e.g. will I have a line like ConverterHolder<TDataType, TControlDataType> = Expression....;. What will the expression be to perform the conversion?

Comment: @user1400716: If you're new to C#, expression trees are to complicated (it's how you compile code at runtime).  Just go with `Convert.ChangeType`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the detailed explaination and solution.

Comment: I've been reading up on Expression trees but the examples given don't really relate to type conversion and don't involve a holder class. I would be very interested to understand your suggestion. Could you expand on this please? I could create another question if required.

Comment: @user1400716: The point of the holder class is just to hold a different compiled expression tree for every pair of types.  You want something like `Expression.Lambda<Func<TIn, TOut>>(Expression.Convert(parameter, typeof(TOut)), parameter)` where `parameter` is `Expression.Parameter(typeof(TIn))`.  Exact syntax may vary a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your constraints don't define a relationship between `TDataType` and `TControlDataType`, so the compiler can't verify that the conversion will succeed. Unfortunately, there is no relationship between `float` and `decimal` that you'll be able to use to define a constraint. However, you should be able to use a `TypeConverter` or `Convert.X` to provide the conversion.